# Renaming files Powershell, Cannot rename file does not exist

Tags: regex, powershell

I try to remove " - 13234" from a bunch of files recursively. And if the file is already present after removing that part it should add (1), (2) and so on after the new file name.

I tested it on a small set of files and that was working fine. Now I tried it on a larger test set and it gave me some errors.

Like: Cannot rename file does not exist
Like: Cannot create a file when file already exist

For a lot of files it looks like it is doing fine actually.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem <location> -recurse -file | sort name | group-object -property {$_.fullname -replace "(.*)-.*?(\..*?)$",'$1$2'}
$files | foreach {
    $inc = 0

    if ($_.count -gt 1) {
        rename-item -literalpath $_.group[0].fullname -NewName (($_.group[0].basename -replace "(.*)-.*?$",'$1') + $_.group[0].extension)
        $inc++

    for ($i = $inc; $i -lt $_.count; $i++) {

        rename-item -literalpath $_.group[$i].fullname -NewName (($_.group[$i].basename -replace "(.*)-.*?$",'$1') + "($i)" + $_.group[$i].extension)
    }
    }
    else {
        rename-item -literalpath $_.group.fullname -NewName (($_.group.basename -replace "(.*)-.*?$",'$1') + $_.group.extension)   
}
}
```

Comment: If you move the initializer for $inc ($inc = 0) outside the loop, does it work?

Comment: Sorting by name is useless when grouping in the next step by a modfied fullname which includes the directory. 7 renaming questions in a row and still no end? Your RegEx doesn't remove the space in front of the ` - ` delimiter.

Comment: @LotPings, that's true. I'm new to this and to stackoverflow. But I try to make it work in all the situations. Regex part is indeed not removing the white space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the following files are in the same directory, the script probably will not work.

```
1 - 13234.txt
1.txt
```

The script first tries to change "1 - 13234.txt" to "1. txt".
You had better first check the existence of the file.

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse |
where BaseName -match "(.*)-" |
Group-Object { $_.DirectoryName + "\" + $Matches[1].TrimEnd() + $_.Extension } |
foreach {
    $fi = [IO.FileInfo]::new($_.Name)
    $i = 0
    $_.Group | Rename-Item -NewName {
        do {
            $newName = $fi.DirectoryName + "\" + $fi.BaseName + $(if($i){"($i)"}) + $fi.Extension
            $script:i++
        } while (Test-Path $newName)
        $newName
    } -PassThru
}
```

Comment: this worked with a larger test set without getting an error. Only files with the following structure "- 664569" as BaseName are not picked-up. For the rest this looks promising.

Comment: I intentionally excluded them, but I changed the code to include them. 
In addition, I changed  to check existing filename every time.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
$Path = '<PATH TO THE ROOTFOLDER WHERE THE FILES TO RENAME ARE FOUND>'

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter '*-*' -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    # obtain the new file basename
    $newBaseName = ($_.BaseName -split '-')[0].Trim()
    $extension   = $_.Extension    # this includes the dot
    $folder      = $_.DirectoryName

    # get an array of all filenames (name only) of the files with a similar name already present in the folder
    $allFiles = @(Get-ChildItem $folder -Filter "$newBaseName*$extension" -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
    # for PowerShell version < 3.0 use this
    # $allFiles = @(Get-ChildItem $folder-Filter "$newBaseName*$extension" | Where-Object { !($_.PSIsContainer) } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)

    # construct the new filename
    $newFileName = $newBaseName + $extension

    if ($allFiles.Count) {
        $count = 1
        while ($allFiles -contains $newFileName) {
            $newFileName = "{0}({1}){2}" -f $newBaseName, $count++, $extension
        }
    }

    Write-Host "Renaming '$($_.FullName)' to '$newFileName'"
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newFileName -Force
}
```

Hope that helps